# "Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound" when returning lastInsertID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My insert statement looked like this earlier:

```
   public function insert($table, $parameters)
    {
        $query = sprintf('insert into %s (%s) VALUES (%s)', $table, implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)), ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters)));
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        return $statement->execute();
    }
```

Now I need to return the id of the last inserted row since I have another insert to be performed right after this one, using this new id. So I modified the insert statement to this:

```
public function insert($table, $parameters)
{
    $query = sprintf('insert into %s (%s) VALUES (%s)', $table, implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)), ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters)));
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

But it is giving me this error when I run it:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

Here is the function call part:

```
$productid = $app['database']->insert('products', [
    'name' => $name,
    'address' => $address,
    'city' => $city,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'zip' => $zip,
    'customerid' => $customer,
    'sno1'=> $serialnumber
]);
```

I'm unsure why it is caused. Usually this happens when the binding of variables does not take place as far as I know. But I haven't modified that part and the return is done after the statement is executed. So I'm confused. Help is appreciated.

Comment: GIGO. var_dump($parameters)

Comment: You're not passing any values to be bound into your parameters when you execute.

Comment: Are you even using query parameters?  This looks like string interpolation *disguised as* query parameters.  What's the actual resulting query you try to execute?

Comment: @David the query will look something like `insert into table (key1, key2) values (:key1, :key2)` so it is using parameters.

Comment: @delboy1978uk 

array(7) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Name" ["address"]=> string(13) "RandomAddress" ["city"]=> string(4) "city" ["phone"]=> string(6) "123123" ["zip"]=> string(4) "1203" ["customerid"]=> string(2) "11" ["sno1"]=> string(7) "0kK102k" } 

I'm sure the array is getting passed. Since the insert works properly in the first code piece I provided.

Comment: @David: Yes I am using query parameters. I shall add the insert function call part in the original post.

Comment: @Nick: Perhaps, but where are the values for those parameters being bound?  The error pretty strongly implies that they're not, and I don't see any attempt to do so in the code.

Comment: @David absolutely! that is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `$parameters` to your `execute` call i.e.

```
    $statement->execute($parameters);
```

Comment: Ah this worked! But I'm confused why it worked even without binding the parameters when I simply used 'return $statement->execute()'.

Comment: It shouldn't have worked. Were you actually checking the return value? It should have been false (which would have made `$productid` look like 0.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Yes, the return value was 0, however the insert command did execute properly, so I did not suspect it to be a binding issue.